# How to set border dynamically in rdlc report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, report, rdlc

I use rdlc report to generate tourist table.

I want to set bottom border just in some record (not all record).

How can i do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't Know Exactly what is some records u mean?

If u r displaying the records  based on some grouping,then if u add border to the group footer den border will appear only after those record before the group footer.

Comment: Grouping will help here.. whatever footer content you are adding, you can outline by darkening the boarders.